# Conver a .htm to a reactjs file to work on localhost

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

im working in reactjs creating a website, and all my files are created in javascript, and when the run they are all at localhost:300/home, localhost:300/invite,etc
Now i wanted to created a form, and i used bootstrap and html, and i created a file .htm.
My problem is, how I can convert it to a path? Like localhost:300/assist

This is my file html, created in a folder Assistencia

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Formulário de Assistência</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css"
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class = "container">
       <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-6">
       
        <div class="card">
            <div class = "card-body">
        <h1> Pedido de Assistência </h1>
        <form id="form-contato">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nome" >Nome: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type = "text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Introduza o seu nome ">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for ="email">Email: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Introduza o seu email ">
            </div>
    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for ="aparelho">Equipamento: </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Introduza o nome do equipamento ">
            </div>
    
            <div class = "form-group">
                <label for="mensagem">Mensagem: </label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Digite o problema do equipamento"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group text-center" >
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar </button>
            </div>
    
            <div class =" altert alert-danger ">
                Preencha o campo <span id="campo-erro"></span> !
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class ="card-body">
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3002.24562723669!2d-8.510244526470451!3d41.19461821588249!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd2462171b81bd9f%3A0x7be7763fa41be50!2sMegapositivo%20Lda!5e0!3m2!1spt-PT!2spt!4v1636746275861!5m2!1spt-PT!2spt" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
      </div> 
    </div>
    
    <script src="js/formulario.js"></script>
    <script src = "js/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the part where i try to put a path

```
import React from 'react';
import Assist from '../components/Assistencia'


const AssistPage = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Assist/>
        </>
    );
};

export default AssistPage
```

Comment: Does this work? https://xpico.csb.app/ If so, try checking out my answer for full explanation... 

Answer (score 1):

To add paths in your SPA React App, you need to use a React Router framework like [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/).

In simple steps, install React Router:

```sh
npm i react router
```

In your `index.js` where you load your App, mount the router:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Once you have got your Router setup done, in your App page, which I presume your main page, do this:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Assist from "../components/Assist";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/assist" component={Assist} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I hope this gave you an idea.

**CodeSandbox**

- [Source Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-drake-xpico)
- [Demo](https://xpico.csb.app/)